# Getting "Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~1kceB6wqP_-41XWyDmGvog==/com.example.iplscore-XiE_yzRxa3HJApEmriciAQ==/base.apk" error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, retrofit

I am making an app using fragments and Retrofit. While running the app it runs without any error but the fragments are not loading. I am getting this error in the logcat.

This is the main activity. I used same code in other app and it ran very well

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var viewModel : CricketViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val cricketRepo = (application as CricketApplication).repository

        val viewModelFactory = CricketViewModelFactory(cricketRepo)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this , viewModelFactory).get(CricketViewModel::class.java)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.iplFragment2 , R.id.otherMatchesFragment))

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navContainer) as NavHostFragment
        navController = binding.navContainer.getFragment<NavHostFragment>().navController
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

This is the fragment where i am getting the data. I have using view model and observer. Toast is displaying the data but fragment is not

```
class IplFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var cricketViewModel: CricketViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentIplBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentIplBinding.inflate(inflater , container , false)
        cricketViewModel = (activity as MainActivity).viewModel

        cricketViewModel.cRicket.observe(viewLifecycleOwner , Observer {

    //       binding.tvData.text =it.data[0].series_id
            Toast.makeText(context , " $it.data" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.d("iplfragment" , "$it.data")
        })

        return binding.root
    }

}
```

This is the main activity layout. The fragment container view is used. The fragment is visible in the design view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/navContainer"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navgraph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.997"
        app:menu="@menu/menu" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This is the fragment. I have used sample text to test whether data is displayed or not

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/purple_200"
    tools:context=".ui.IplFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/tvData"
        android:text="IPL Match" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="IPL" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This is the error log. I have deleted and re installed app couple of times. App is running but the fragment are not loading

```
   Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~1kceB6wqP_-41XWyDmGvog==/com.example.iplscore-XiE_yzRxa3HJApEmriciAQ==/base.apk': I/O error
01:44:18.943  E  Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~1kceB6wqP_-41XWyDmGvog==/com.example.iplscore-XiE_yzRxa3HJApEmriciAQ==/base.apk': I/O error
01:44:18.945  E  failed to add asset path '/data/app/~~1kceB6wqP_-41XWyDmGvog==/com.example.iplscore-XiE_yzRxa3HJApEmriciAQ==/base.apk'
                 java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~1kceB6wqP_-41XWyDmGvog==/com.example.iplscore-XiE_yzRxa3HJApEmriciAQ==/base.apk
                    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeLoad(Native Method)
                    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.<init>(ApkAssets.java:295)
                    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.loadFromPath(ApkAssets.java:144)
                    at android.app.ResourcesManager.loadApkAssets(ResourcesManager.java:454)
                    at android.app.ResourcesManager.access$000(ResourcesManager.java:72)
                    at android.app.ResourcesManager$ApkAssetsSupplier.load(ResourcesManager.java:168)
                    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createAssetManager(ResourcesManager.java:530)
                    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResourcesImpl(ResourcesManager.java:612)
                    at android.app.ResourcesManager.findOrCreateResourcesImplForKeyLocked(ResourcesManager.java:664)
                    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResources(ResourcesManager.java:1011)
                    at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources(ResourcesManager.java:1114)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:2372)
                    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1751)
                    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1737)
                    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1506)
                    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3029)
                    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadUnbadgedIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:290)
                    at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.getBadgedIcon(SystemUIToast.java:284)
                    at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.inflateToastView(SystemUIToast.java:198)
                    at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.<init>(SystemUIToast.java:90)
                    at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.<init>(SystemUIToast.java:77)
                    at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastFactory.createToast(ToastFactory.java:78)
                    at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI.lambda$showToast$0(ToastUI.java:113)
                    at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI.$r8$lambda$w_gPCh3F8Xxn1jN4lkQZoUci71c(Unknown Source:0)
                    at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:16)
                    at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI.showToast(ToastUI.java:140)
                    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.CommandQueue$H.handleMessage(CommandQueue.java:1431)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```